Svelte seems to react to assigned variable change
Let’s suppose I have this as main page:
<script>
    import Child from "./Child.svelte";

    let person = { name: "" };
</script>

<Child {person} />

And this as a child:
<script>
    export let person;

    let name;
    $: name = person.name;
</script>

<input bind:value={name} />

You can try it here.
The reason I don’t directly bind person.name is because I don’t want to mutate parent objects at all, I prefer to throw an event.
I expected to be able to modify the name variable of the child component by typing values in the input. A modification in the parent element  However it doesn’t work at all, because the input remains empty whatever I type in it.
After having created this minimal example and put console.log everywhere, it seems that the line $: name = person.name is triggered right after I type something in the input field, while it shouldn’t because person.name doesn’t change, the assigned variable does.
It is surely very easy but I can’t understand why this behaviour happens, so thanks in advance for any help

I find the observed behavior very strange too, and I can't come up with any arguments for why this should be the intended behavior. I suspect it's a bug. Give it some time and see if anyone can explain why it's like this, and if no one can, I recommend you to file a bug report.

@PeppeL-G As I put in my answer I have finally found a workaround. Apparently, either you use mutable data and there is no issue, or you need to precise that you only use immutable data. I don’t know if it can cause some troubles, for instance if you use both immutable and mutable data in the same component (which is weird).

I finally found a solution for my case. As I said in the original post, I try to avoid mutating any object’s attribute, so in fact I can add <svelte:options immutable /> in Child.svelte.
And it works! This way, Svelte doesn’t update the component until its parent is reassigned. I found some details here.

If you only want to pass person.name as initial value, your code is wrong.  Do this:
<script>
    export let person;

    let name = person.name;
</script>

<input bind:value={name} />

Just initialization.
UPDATE 2024-07-08
If you want to also update if the person object changes:
<script>
    export let person;
</script>

<input bind:value={person.name} />

Trying to get ahead of things you haven't explained:  If you don't want to mutate the given person object, pass a copy.

I would like that if person changes from another source, it is also updated in the field. Even if I am not sure if it is a good idea.

@TitouanBizet see update.
